# Using reference variable without declaring them ??? [From a confused and inexperienced programmer]

Tags: java, operators

I'm pretty new to java. I just recently knew how to create an object and make use of Dot operator so I'm not yet an experienced programmer...

The following code I got from a website while trying to do research about objects in java :

```
class Time { 
int hour, minute; 
double second; 

public Time () { 
this.hour = 0; 
this.minute = 0; 
this.second = 0.0; 
} 

public Time (int hour, int minute,     
double second) { 
this.hour = hour; 
this.minute = minute; 
this.second = second; 
} 

public static void main (String[]   
args) { 

// one way to create and initialize  
a Time object 
Time t1 = new Time (); 
t1.hour = 11; 
t1.minute = 8; 
t1.second = 3.14159; 
System.out.println (t1); 

// another way to do the same thing 
Time t2 = new Time (11, 8, 3.14159); 
System.out.println (t2); 
} 
}
```

If you noticed, the code contains 'this.' reference variable, here is my point : if this is a completed source code then how on earth can it even possible to use the reference thing without declaring them.
Forgive me if I'm  wrong, but perhaps it isn't completed yet.
I'm confused, any good explanation is appreciated.
Thanks for reading this, guys.

Answer (score 0):

The methods using `this` are constructors. You could use it to create a `Time` object in the `main` method, like so:

```
Time t = new Time();
```

This would call the first constructor, where `this.hour`, `this.minute`, and `this.second` all refer to variables belonging to `t` - `t.hour`, `t.minute`, and `t.second`, respectively. The constructor assigns `0` to all these variables. The second constructor works quite similarly:

```
Time t2 = new Time(9, 30, 2.0);
```

This works just like the above example, except it calls the second constructor, assigning the variables of `t2` to the parameters passed to the constructor. In this case, `t2.hour` is set to `9`, `t2.minute` to `30`, and `t2.second` to `2.0`.

Comment: oh, so 'this' actually refers to 't' variable ?